# TDataset --> Pointer to rows cols matrix?

Tags: c, delphi, pointers, matrix, tdataset

I am writing a windows application in Lazarus/FreePascal (like Delphi). I have a [TDataset](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/fcl/db/tdataset.html) object that is populated by **5000 rows, 2 columns** of numerical values.
I need to pass this data to a `C` function that I am importing statically from a .dll library.

Here is an excerpt from the library's manual that explains what format its parameters should be in:

```
flan_index_t flann_build_index(float* dataset,
    int rows,
    int cols,
    float* speedup,
    struct FLANNParameters* flann_params);
```

> This function builds an index and return a reference to it. The
> arguments expected by this function are as follows: dataset, rows and
> cols - are used to specify the input dataset of points:
> **dataset is a pointer to a rows  cols matrix stored in row-major
> order (one feature on each row)**

Can I simply pass the TDataSet object? Do I have to do something to it first so that the pointer is in the right form?

Comment: Could this be the right way to do it? Move(DataSet, DataPointer[0], SizeOf(DataSet));

Comment: No, a TDataSet is a class that encapsulates teh connection to a datafile or sql server. It doesn't point to the data expected by the function.

Comment: No. The TDataset has a different structure than the required by the function. You don't specify which size has each item of the matrix, there are several types for numeric values. Sorry, I cannot add (+1) for using Object Pascal, even if I want to ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously you can't pass the `TDataSet` object. It is a FreePascal object, and the function seems to expect a pointer to a `float` (which is probably a pointer to a `Single` in FreePascal). It probably expects a two-dimensional array of `float`'s. You have to pass another pointer to `float` and a pointer to a `FLANNParameters` structure as well.

`Move()` won't work either. A `TDataSet` is not an array.

I guess you'll have to declare an array like Uwe said, populate it using your dataset and pass the array:

```
type
  PMyFloatArray = ^TFloatArray;
  TMyFloatArray = array[0..4999, 0..1] of Single;

var
  MyArray: PMyFloatArray;
  idx: flan_index_t;

begin
  New(MyArray);
  try

    // Fill array using your TDataSet...
    // set up other parameters... 

    idx := flann_build_index(MyArray, 5000, 2, &speedup, etc...);

    // ...

  finally
    Dispose(MyArray);
  end;
end;
```

### Shameless plug

Please read my [Pitfalls of Conversion](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-convert.html) article about converting function declarations from C to Delphi (and probably FreePascal on Win32). Now I'm at it, you may want to read my article [Addressing Pointers](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-pointers.html) too.

Comment: Would there happen to be a way to fill the array by reference instead of by duplicating the values in a loop?

Comment: Can I maybe convert it to a TMemoryStream, and then copy it to a pointer?.. Or is that a waste of time?

Comment: The data are somewhere, and you use the DataSet to get them from there. They don't have to be there in one block.

Comment: I have read parts of both of your articles many times over the past week or two. They are both extremely useful articles! Thank you very much for creating them; very impressive :)

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't pass the dataset directly. The naming "dataset" might imply that, but the meaning is totally different. You have to pass a pointer to a float matrix to the function. To implement this you should declare an array[0..4999, 0..1] of float (probably double) and fill it from the dataset.

Comment: float = Single, double = Double, assuming this is Win32 and FreePascal doesn't have different definitions than Delphi.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not very familiar with C types.

Comment: See the shameless plug in my answer. ;-)

Comment: If this array contains 1 milllion items, would this be a significant speed delay?

Comment: @Mike, delay compared to what? As passing the dataset is no option, you have no chance as to go the array way. So it needs the time it needs.

Answer (score 0):

Using Rudy's solution as a base  (Thanks by the way!) I came up with this:

```
 with Datasource1.DataSet do
  begin
    Open;
    First;
    field_count := FieldCount;
    record_count := RecordCount;

    row := 0;
    while not EOF do
    begin
      for col := 0 to field_count - 1 do
        MyArray[row, col] := Fields.Fields[col].AsFloat;
      row := row + 1; //Shift to next row in array
      Next; //Shift to next row in dataset
    end;
  end;
```

Seems to work great; and a lot faster than I expected.